# How to insert a HTML fragment and hold a reference to the outer element?

Tags: javascript, dom, element, innerhtml

I've always wondered how this jQuery feature works: `$('<span>Hello world</span>')[0]`
That is supposed to return a reference to the newly created span element. How can I achieve the same result using the native DOM methods? insertAdjacentHTML? innerHTML? documentFragment?
I need to insert a HTML fragment and hold a reference to the outer element without the need of using createElement/appendChild.

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you have the restriction of not using "createElement()" or "appendChild()"?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to create an element, set its innerHTML, and return the first child. The container element is never added to the DOM:

```
var el = document.createElement('div');
el.innerHTML = '<span>Hello world</span>';
console.log(el.firstChild);
```

If that's wrapped in a function, I believe the original container will be eligible for garbage collection as soon as the child is appended somewhere else.

jQuery seems to be doing something more sophisticated, checking if the string contains a single tag or not, and creating a fragment for more complicated strings. See [the `parseHTML` method](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#l465) on jQuery's source code.